# How to make website responsive down until certain width, then shrink to fit?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using this viewport metatag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

I have designed my website responsively. But I can not account for a responsive design for devices with a smaller than 320px width. How can I let the website shrink to fit (and not horizontally scroll) on devices < 320px width?

Comment: By default, most elements *will* shrink to fit, unless you're preventing them from doing so in your CSS. Mobile-first design is based around creating a flexible, single-column layout and then modifying that via media queries for larger screens.

Answer (score -1):

You got to remove margin and padding from the body, and set its width to 100%,
in order not to rely on the default width applied by the browser write this in   tags within your html or call it from CSS file

```
body{padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;}
```

set a max-width:

```
#image-grid img {max-width: 100%;}
```

Also for fonts

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
h1 { font-size: 30px; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by disks?

Comment: I edited my answer, is this not working for you ?